# make test doesn't do anything for mocha tests

Tags: makefile

I'm following this example: http://brianstoner.com/blog/testing-in-nodejs-with-mocha/

I defined a Makefile in my root directory:

```
REPORTER = dot

test:
  @NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha \
    --reporter $(REPORTER) \

test-w:
  @NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha \
    --reporter $(REPORTER) \
    --watch

.PHONY: test test-w
```

But when I run 'make test' it says "make: Nothing to be done for `test'."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out Makefiles are tab-sensitive -- and those were clobbered when I cut-n-paste the file...

In vi, i turned on tabs and spacing to fix it:

```
vi Makefile
:set list
```

Now you can retab the file and ensure you are doing it correctly.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, it helped me out! :P

Comment: I'm using another editor, but you answer helped me anyway. I've previously replaced all tabs by 4 spaces – following the standard I use – and it broke the tests.